# What is theme music that plays in episode 181 at 07:37 minutes?

Tags: naruto, music

What is the theme song that plays while Subaru embraces Rock Lee?

Answer (score 1):

The soundtrack name is `Nervous`.

You can listen it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRyohGCjdVU